# Union types do not work when combined with `Omit<>`

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

I have the following interfaces:

```
export interface Base {
   a: string;
   b: string;
}

export interface Foo extends Base {
   c: string[];
   type: 'foo';
}

export interface Bar extends Base {
  c: string;
  type: 'bar';
}
```

From these interfaces I define the union type `MyType` in this way:

```
export type MyType = Foo | Bar;
```

The type `MyType` is thus inferred as:

```
{ 
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string | string[];
  type: 'foo' | 'bar';
}
```

which is the intended behavior. If I define a function like:

```
function testFunction1(param: MyType): MyType {
    return param;
}
```

It works fine, but when I replace `MyType` with `Omit<MyType, 'b'>` the compiler doesn't want to accept the code in any way. Example:

```
function testFunction2(param: Omit<MyType, 'b'>): MyType {
    return {...param, b: 'a'};
}
```

It returns the following error:

> Type '{ b: string; c: string | string[]; type: "foo" | "bar"; a: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyType'.
>
> Type '{ b: string; c: string | string[]; type: "foo" | "bar"; a: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
>
> Types of property 'c' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Even if I'm sure that the returned value is compatible with `MyType`, since I'm changing a property defined in `Base`. How can I combine `Omit` and union types?

#### Note:

I'm trying to refine a type in a large codebase, for this reason, I don't want to force the type with a type assertion everywhere (e.g. `return {...} as MyType`). In the codebase there's a large use of `Omit<>` and when I refactored `MyType` in this way everything stopped working.

### Typescript Playground

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=23&pc=1#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBZZAVV6C8CAYlFAgD4IBCAhjANzCiSyICWAdnCDAGY0BjdLQDO6AN7AE0mgC4EIuDE4BzRtIQAjeYuUc1wAL5Nw0eAk7c+g9CTLhuHACYjqNMQkkaBOpaoDaALrq0iho8gDkvKQRjMbMZuxcPPxCbjAIDiDOrqISUgg+Cn76IWEgkZp0sUZMvACuHAJwbFAcSCCKRI3NrRwAjAAUEHQ0ALbyWLhoAJSTOHieBdIwIHD1MO0jMONxdT0tbR1dB30ATMOjEwgA8mNscAA8U3gANAgRmhEAfHOYC2glhoEKt1ptPAA6KHbcbvbQfGgRQxxIA)

Comment: `Omit` doesn't distribute across unions; you need to make your own distributive version and use that instead, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgBQMW) and in the linked questions and answers above.

Comment: Also note, when you say "the type `MyType` is thus inferred as `{⋯}`" , it's not true.  The type you wrote is a supertype of `MyType`, so every `MyType` is one of those, but not vice versa.

Comment: @jcalz thank you. I just wanted to modify the `MyType` type since the codebase already uses `Omit`. So are you confirming there's no way of solving the error only changing `MyType`?

Comment: Yes, confirmed.  You could make `MyType` the non-union type you claimed it's inferred as, but that would allow `{type: "foo", c: "oops", ⋯}`  which you don't want.  `Omit` is the wrong tool for the job, whether or not your code base already uses it.

Comment: @jcalz would you advise something in place of `Omit`? the `DistributiveOmit` in the linked question does the job, but it sounds like I shouldn't use `Omit` at all